# Set a default for string value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `activities` table with a string value called `viewed`. I would like to set the default value of the string `viewed` to `uncheck` instead of `null`. But I can get it to work.

I've created a migration,

```
class AddDefaultToViewedInActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_column_default :activities, :viewed, uncheck
  end

end
```

But when I run `rake db:migrate` the change doesn't happen.

*** update ***

It looks like I missed some brackets,

```
change_column_default(:activities, :viewed, 'uncheck')
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

As you currently wrote it, `uncheck` is a method call, not a string. It should be

```
class AddDefaultToViewedInActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default :activities, :viewed, "uncheck"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup. Missed some brackets. I'm going to take a break ;).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
class AddDefaultToViewedInActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_column_default :activities, :viewed, default: 'uncheck'
  end

end
```